# Restoring the root of a working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Because of [some Windows/Linux crossover problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19003/permanently-mounting-windows-ntfs-partition-fully-enabled) I've somehow corrupted the root directory of my SVN working copy. If I try to update it, the client complains that it's not a WC. The subdirectories are still ok.

Is there a way to restore the root without having to check out all the subdirectories again? (It's a rather large repo). I've tried cleanup already, but this problem is beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when a working copy gets corrupted there's nothing you can do beyong checking out a fresh one and copying pending changes with WinMerge or a similar tool.

If you are 100% sure that only the root folder is mangled, you can checkout a fresh copy in a new folder and adjust the "Checkout Depth" option so it won't fetch children. Afterwards, you copy the rest of the folder from Windows explorer.